# Sum the highest scores per user and track

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

This is probably a easy one, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out.
This is my table:

```
uid  |  userID  |  trackID  |  carID  |  highscoreDate  |  highscore
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1        1            1         1           [date]         123
 2        1            1         1           [date]          44
 3        2            2         1           [date]         222
 4        2            1         1           [date]          28
 5        1            2         1           [date]          17
```

I would like to get the **SUM** of the **highest** highscores for each user and track. In the data above that would give:

```
 user 1: 140
 user 2: 250
```

Comment: do u need highest score of each user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a subselect first.

Something like

```
SELECT userID, SUM(highscore)
FROM (
    SELECT userID, trackID, MAX(highscore) highscore
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY userID, trackID
  ) s
GROUP BY userID
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/717cb/3)